# Read and change @data in an object variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datatables

First, the scenario. I want to display some data with `DataTables`. For that, I created a generic service called `TableService` that receives some params and one of them is an `IQueryable<T>`.

`TableService` checks the values from the form, sorts the data, applies conditions and takes the record for a specific page. It returns an object with only the records to display.

```
public object GetRecords(string draw, string length, string start, string columnSort,
    string columnDirectrion, string search, IFormCollection form, IQueryable<T> data,
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition)
{
    var drawValue = form.GetValueOrDefault("draw", draw);
    var lengthValue = form.GetValueOrDefault("length", length);
    var startValue = form.GetValueOrDefault("start", start);
    var sortColumn = columnSort ?? form["columns[" + form["order[0][column]"].FirstOrDefault() + 
                     "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
    var sortColumnDirection = form.GetValueOrDefault("order[0][dir]", columnDirectrion);
    var searchValue = form.GetValueOrDefault("search[value]", search);

    int pageSize = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(length) ? Convert.ToInt32(lengthValue) : 10;
    int skip = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(start) ? Convert.ToInt32(startValue) : 0;

    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDirection)))
        data = data.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDirection);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
        data = data.Where(condition);

    var recordsTotal = data.Count();

    var rtn = data.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize);
    var jsonData = new { draw = drawValue, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, 
                   recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = rtn };
    return jsonData;
}
```

The function is really working and the result is ok. An example in the image below.

[image]

Where is my problem then? Some fields are IDs and I want to replace the IDs with the real value. So, for that, I want to read the output of this function and change the `@data`. My idea was:

- read the `@data` and convert them to the original type (in the image *AzureCost*)
- create a new `List` with the data from the original type and the real values instead of the IDs
- replace `@data` with my new list of values

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please share more code?How do you call this method and how do you pass the data?

Comment: the full project is here https://github.com/erossini/AdminLTEWithASPNETCore/tree/feature/excel-import and `TableService` is here https://github.com/erossini/AdminLTEWithASPNETCore/blob/feature/excel-import/PSC.Services.AspNetCore/TableAPIs/TableService.cs